# How to use include() to include image in <img src=

Tags: php, html

I need help with HTML and PHP. How I can use include() in `<img src"">` ?

Example:

```
<?php

some code here

$page_banner = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/page-banner.png';

some code here

?>

some code here

<img src=<?php include($page_banner); ?>>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Sorry for bad english. Google helps me.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need\want include here its simply.

```
<img src='<?php echo $page_banner; ?>'>
```

src= is the URI to the image

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the src attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use `include()` for files, not for variables. So just use the variable without `include()`.

```
<img src='<?php echo $page_banner; ?>'>
```

Don't forget the quotes around the image path.